# Integrate stripe gem with rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

How to use `stripe` payment get way in my application?

I've added `gem 'stripe'` to my Gemfile and I've run `bundle install`, but now I am getting confuse in the flow of development.

Comment: What particular problem  do You have?

Comment: I dont knwo how to use this gem

Comment: Stripe has a pretty good documentation and API for several languages. It's hard to understand that you are not able to get ahead just a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

It's a general points for using Strip payments API:
https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart

How I used it in my app:

```
# Create user in strip. It returns `stripe_customer_id`
Stripe::Customer.create
#or retrieve user
Stripe::Customer.retrieve
```

after it you can make a charge:

```
Stripe::Charge.create(
:amount => amount,
:currency => currency,
:customer => stripe_customer_id, #It was received from create customer
:description => description)
```

More details you can find [this](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#intro)